# How to see the current working directory in WinGHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci, working-directory, winghci

I've started to teach myself Haskell, and for that I've installed [The Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) for Windows. I'm using `WinGHCi` as of now. I learned that it has command `:cd` which is used to change directory. But the question is, how would I know which directory I'm currently in? Without knowing that first why would I want to change directory.  I searched a lot but couldn't find the answer.

Please tell me if there is a way to know the current working directory. Preferably I would like to configure the command prompt itself to show the current directory, pretty much like Linux's Console.

---

Following @Daniel's suggestion, I did these:

- Since I worked on Windows 7, there is no `.ghci` file (I think it is for Unix-like OS), so I created a file `ghci.conf` in `C:\Users\Apelles\AppData\Roaming\ghc` folder, as [it is instructed here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html).
- Copy pasted the script from Daniel's answer to `ghci.conf`.
- Then I started `ghci.exe` which is the console-like window. I noticed that it loaded few more modules than it usually used to load before. Here is the snapshot:

[image]

As you can see it loads more modules, and the last line says,

> Can't parse prompt string. Use Haskell syntax.

What does it mean? Which line is causing problem (from the following script)?

```
let cur fill = do { cwd <- System.Directory.getCurrentDirectory; return (":set prompt \"" ++ cwd ++ fill ++ " \""); }
:def doprompt (\_ -> cur ">")
:def mycd (\dir -> System.Directory.setCurrentDirectory dir >> cur ">")
:doprompt
```

Also, if I rename `ghci.conf` file to some random name, and then start `ghci.exe`, it loads these modules:
[image]

As I said before, it loads less number of modules, which means *with ghci.conf*, `ghci.exe` does something successfully, but fails at some point. How to fix that?

Comment: Try `Prelude> :! pwd` (or whatever Windows' equivalent of pwd is). I think WinGHCi runs an ordinary ghci underneath, so that should work.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That works great. Would it be possible to configure the command prompt itself?

Comment: Yes, you can configure the prompt with `:set prompt Whatever` (type `:?` for a short help on ghci commands). That's per session, however. To make it kind of permanent, do it in your `.ghci` file (I think they're called differently on Windows, don't remember what). I'm not sure how to set it to the current directory, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer: `:set prompt Whatever`? What should I put in place of `Whatever` so that it shows the current working directory? `:set prompt :!pwd` doesn't help here.

Comment: No, indeed it doesn't work that way. I don't know how one would do that, maybe the [users guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/ghci.html) helps. I'm convinced it's possible, but I have never done any such customisation, so I'm afraid I can't help beyond giving general ideas.

Comment: @DanielFischer On Windows, `cd` with no further arguments _prints_ the current directory instead of _setting_ it.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: On Windows, `cd` neither *prints* nor *sets* the current directory. It rather is used to *change directory* (i.e to navigate), hence the name *cd*.

Comment: That it loads more packages with the `ghci.conf` is unsurprising, the dot-ghci uses `System.Directory`, hence the `directory` package and its dependencies have to be loaded.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yup. That understood immediately seeing them. Actually I wanted to say that it does something successfully, but fails at some point. (edited the question)

Comment: For the "Can't parse prompt string. Use Haskell syntax.", I don't know. Could be something with Windows' path separator. What does `System.Directory.getCurrentDirectory >>= print` output?

Comment: Unrelated: if it's not too much hassle (and if you don't plan to do development, it isn't I think, there ought to be an installer), you should upgrade to a newer GHC, the current version is 7.4.2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13253/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-nawaz)

Comment: @Nawaz did you find a solution to this "Current directory scenario"? i started with haskell now and am stuck with the same issue..as a workaround i found that `:cd <absolute_directory_path>` will help. and the WinGHCi starts with the current directory set to where the binary is installed.. Please do let me know if you find out anything. Thanks.

Comment: @Koushik: No. I'm not studying Haskell these says. I will come back to it once I get free time. :-)

Answer (score 32):

`System.Directory.getCurrentDirectory` from the [`directory`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory) package.

Comment: Useful alternative, but should not be the preferred way to do this. This is a call to a language function, which does not help the user learn GHCi's commands. It's like if I asked how to type the letter `~` and you gave me the Alt-code (Type "Alt 126"), instead of telling me to hit the '~' key.

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure if this is the "right" way to do it, but since `:!` allows shell commands, you can also get it with the appropriate shell command (of your OS) for reading out the directory or the content (so `cd`, `ls` and the likes). For example, you can write:

```
:! cd
```

It depends what do you need the directory for. If you just want to print it out in your console, then this can help.

All the best!

Comment: certainly the simplier one indeed

Answer (score 4):

A poor man's solution to set the ghci prompt to the current working directory would be putting

```
let cur fill = do { cwd <- System.Directory.getCurrentDirectory; return (":set prompt \"" ++ cwd ++ fill ++ " \""); }
:def doprompt (\_ -> cur ">")
:def mycd (\dir -> System.Directory.setCurrentDirectory dir >> cur ">")
:doprompt
```

in the `.ghci` file.

In the first line, we define `cur :: String -> IO String` that gets the current directory and returns the ghci command to set the prompt accordingly. Then we define a ghci command `doprompt` that performs that action and a command to change directory and set the prompt. The last line executes `:doprompt` on startup.

Unfortunately, that doesn't make `:cd dir` reflect the change of directory, one would have to do a manual `:doprompt` afterwards, or use `:mycd` to change the directory.

To avoid too long prompts, one could manipulate the result of `getCurrentDirectory` by dropping an initial part of the file path.

Another drawback to that simple approach is that the prompt doesn't contain information about the loaded modules anymore. I believe all that could be overcome, but I'm not motivated enough to do the digging now.

Comment: Let me try this. For the time being, +1 for attempting to answer.

Comment: I tried it on Windows, and it didn't work. I added things which I did, to my question. See it.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Any indication what failed? (I see no edit to your question yet)

Comment: Sorry, it took time to edit my question. I tried to post as much information as I could. It is done now. :-)

Comment: Oops. I forgot to give +1 for the attempt. :|

Answer (score 2):

In the ghci command prompt type `:! cd`, it will give you the output for the current directory. In general, use `:!` followed by shell commands to run any shell command in ghci command prompt. The shells are different on Windows and Mac/Linux, so the commands you can use will be different.